# error CS8773: "Feature 'global using directive' is not available in C# 9.0" after downgrade from net6.0 to net5.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-5, .net-6.0

I have a project that was initially created for .NET 6 but then I needed to downgrade it to .NET 5.
I changed Target framework in Project Properties and tried to compile. As a result I received a bunch of the errors:

```
GlobalUsings.g.cs(2,1,2,29): error CS8773: Feature 'global using directive' is not available in C# 9.0. Please use language version 10.0 or greater.
```

File GlobalUsings.g.cs is created automatically and it reappears every time after compilation.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Finally I found that the reason is an extra property ImplicitUsings in the project file that is not supported by .net 5.0.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I needed to remove **ImplicitUsings** from the file.

Comment: it worked..thanks...I changed my framework back to **net6.0** based on your diagnosis

Comment: When i did this then my project broke> does one then need to go and add the using directives back into each program?

Comment: Yes @Zapnologica you need to add the using directives back.

Comment: Weirdly, I also got this Error using **.Net 6** and removing `ImplicitUsings` fixed it as well.

Answer (score 19):

remove `<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>` in the csproj project file, then can build success

find this solution from [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs2022-preview-60-downgrading-a-net-60-project-to/1570694#T-N1563135)

Answer (score 12):

Remove the tag  indeed work.
But just change the value of it did the trick as well!

`<ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>`

Answer (score 9):

To get rid of this error which is caused by downgrading below net6.0.

Remove the following items from the .csproj file:

1. `<ImplicitUsings>`
2. `<Using Include="..." />`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to remove the `ImplicitUsings` or made changes to the project file. You can tell the build cli to disable it during build process by

```
dotnet build --configuration "Release" --framework "net5.0" /p:ImplicitUsings=false /p:PublishReadyToRun=false
```